# With Excel Dynamic Arrays, is it possible to spill across merged cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

[I'm trying to follow the guidance about [answering one's own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but I'm not 100% sure I'm doing it right]

With Excel Dynamic Arrays, is there a way, when spilling across merged cells, to avoid #SPILL! errors such as is described in [#SPILL! error - Spill into merged cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhXt.png) on support.microsoft.com, where they show this:

[image]

The SORT() function in F2 is failing to spill properly because one of the cells in the spill rage, F6 is merged with another, F7. The proposed solution is to either unmerge the cells causing the problem, or move the dynamic array to somewhere else where there is no obstructing merge.

Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Why yes, I believe there may well be a better way! (Again, see [comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhXt.png) from the one and only JeffA.)

I actually first ran into this by accident a couple of years or so ago, and then a few times since, but I've never been able to figure out exactly how I was doing it. Until now.

And it's really simple; all you do is make sure you apply the merged format *after* inserting the formula causing the #SPILL! error.

Here is the Microsoft support example again. I've removed gridlines and added some borders to make clear where the offending merge is:

[image]

Now here it is once more, but just to the right, in I2:J11, you'll see that I have replicated the same format as is in F2:G11, including the merge that is causing the problem. I've done that for one reason only: to let me copy that format to my clipboard. And in fact as you're looking at it, I have just selected I2:J11 and done that *Copy*.

[image]

OK, so having done the *Copy*, I then select cell F2 (if you want, you can select the whole range, F2:G11, but selecting F2 is sufficient) and I do a *Paste Special->Formatting*. And here is the result:

[image]

You can see that the #SPILL! error has gone, and the SORT(D2:D11) formula in F2 is spilling nicely.

I've checked this on up to date versions of Excel within a Microsoft 365 subscription on:

- **Mac OS:** Excel version 16.68 (22110602), and
- **Windows 11:** Excel version 2211 Build 16.0.15822.20000

I've also checked it in a couple of scenarios different to the one above. To me, that one is a bit contrived; it seems kinda daft to have the situation where spilling was obstructed by only a single merge in a range of cells that was otherwise free of merges. (It is, of course, just the illustration Microsoft chose for their article, so fair enough.) But I *regularly* run into the spill problem in the real world when handling imported data tables with headers so long I have to use "Wrap Text". In that situation, the spill problem means that if I want to have the headers as spilling arrays, I have to tolerate very "high" rows (i.e. their row height is huge), when I would much rather keep the rows a standard height and merge the long headers across multiple rows. This method lets me do that.

But anyway, it is worth pointing out that while the above method does indeed work, it seems to be a wee bit fragile. For example, if, after getting the thing to that final working state I was to simply select cell F2, place my cursor to the right of the SORT() formula, and hit ENTER, then the #SPILL! error would return, despite me having made no real changes to anything. And then, even weirder, if I were to do a simple 'Undo', that would not remove the error. To do that I would, once again, have to copy the pre-formatted range in I2:J11, and then *Paste Special->Formatting* it back into F2 as I did before.

Finally, I have a couple of "followup" questions  -- and this is what I would have asked in the first place, prior to reading Atwood's "answer your own question" comment:

1. Can anyone confirm that the above method does actually work?
2. Can anyone suggest **why** it works (especially given that Microsoft's position seems to be that you cannot do what I believe this method lets you do)?